# Function execute after Ajax request is complete (pure JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, callback

In my application I use MVC model and Views are built with JavaScript DOM API.
On each page I have to check user's information to find out if session is active and if user's role gives him ability to access that page. 
To make this happen, on each page I have "onload" function that triggers "sessionCheck" function which sends AJAX request to controller and returns information with which application makes decisions.
As I said JavaScript is also used to build Views, which means that after "sessionCheck" function I also have "headerView", "sectionView" and other functions that build the structure of page.

So the problem is that, before "sessionCheck" is finished other functions are loaded and nearly for 1-2 seconds users have ability to see what happens on that page and only after that they are transported out of that page by application if that is needed.

I read that there are some solutions in JQuery where "ajax.Complete" functions are available, but I couldn't same solutions in pure JavaScript. Can someone help me to solve this problem ?

This is HTML

```
<body onload="sessionCheckAdmin(); adminHeaderView(); adminUser(); modalView();">
```

sessionCheckAdmin functions looks like this

```
function sessionCheckAdmin()
{
    var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("Code", "3");
        formData.append("Sequence", "27");
        formData.append("TaskId", "All");
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            {
                var array = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                if(array["userRole"] != "Administrator")
                    window.location.href = "task.php";
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "../Controller.php");
        xmlHttp.send(formData);
}
```

Part of PHP controller

```
case 27:
        $array = json_encode($_SESSION);
        echo $array;
        break;
```

Comment: We need to see your code to know exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: @RayonDabre I have updated my post

Comment: Call those functions in `ajax` => `if (xmlHttp.status == 200)`

Comment: @RayonDabre I have already tried that but as I said user sees page for nearly 1-2 seconds and only after that is transported back.

Comment: User will not be able to see it as the methods which create DOM are not invoked yet..makes sense ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Problem is that they don't wait for Ajax request to complete and start executing before that. So maybe for user it's hard to see everything for 1 second or half of that, but for me it's problem.

Comment: I am talking about this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/zwr6trw1/

Comment: @RayonDabre Actually that solved my problem :) Thanks Man :)
I wasn't using else clause, I was writing that straight after if and maybe that was the problem